# What does urlparse.SplitResult() do?

Tags: python, urlparse

I try to search definition from official document about SplitResult(), but I can not find useful information that makes sense to me. Can anyone explain to me according to the code below?

```
> > > import urlparse 
> > > components = urlparse.urlsplit(' http:// example.webscraping.com/ index/') 
> > > print components 
SplitResult( scheme =' http', netloc =' example.webscraping.com', path ='/` index/', query ='', fragment ='') 
> > > print components.path
'/index.html/'
```

Answer (score 0):

It takes a URL and breaks it down into it's components. See here for more information: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Resource_Locator#Syntax